How do I get a deployed Blazor web app to connect to an Azure SQL Server database using the current users details?
I have a .NET 8.0 Blazor web App and an Azure SQL Server DB set up. The app is registered on Azure and I have the requisite ClientID, TenantID and secret set up.
I've added our public IP address to the SQL Server in Azure.
Everything works when I run the app locally. As soon as I publish to the IIS server, it won't connect to the DB. Authorisation works ok, but nothing regarding the DB.
IIS has Windows authentication enabled.
Here's my program.cs:
using HiSS.Body.Components;
using HiSS.DB;
using HiSS.Shared.DBAccess;
using HiSS.Shared.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Authentication with EntraId
//
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
builder.Services.AddAuthenticationCore();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

// Helper services
//
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDBAccess, DataAccessService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppSettingsHelper>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp =>
{
    // Load Azure AD credentials from configuration
    var clientId = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
    var tenantId = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
    var clientSecret = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];

    // Ensure HTTPS settings for Azure AD communication
    return new EntraIDHelper(clientId!, tenantId!, clientSecret!);
});

// Add services to the container.
//
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

// Bootstrap library
//
builder.Services.AddBlazorBootstrap();

// Telerik components
//
builder.Services.AddTelerikBlazor();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization(); 

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();

The appsettings.json file:
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ServicePrincipleObjectId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Domain": "customDomain.onmicrosoft.com", 
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    },
    "DbConfig": {
        "DatabaseName": "<dbname>",
        "ServerName": "<servername>.database.windows.net"
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

The connection string being used to connect to SQL Server is:
"Server=tcp:{_server},1433;Database={_database};Authentication=Active Directory Default;"

Update - I've removed the Authentication setting in the connection string and added getting a token in my sql connection code. Works on my machine but not on the server still. I've debugged it and managed to get this error when trying to get a token:

Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException   HResult=0x80131500
Message=DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the
included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more
information.
https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot

EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for
more information.
https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot

WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload options are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for
more information.
https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot

ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No response received from the managed identity endpoint.

Visual Studio Token provider can't be accessed at C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json

Azure CLI not installed

Az.Accounts module >= 2.2.0 is not installed.

Azure Developer CLI could not be found.   Source=Azure.Identity   StackTrace:    at
Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.d__14.MoveNext()
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at
Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.d__12.MoveNext()
at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception
ex, String additionalMessage, Boolean isCredentialUnavailable)    at
Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.d__12.MoveNext()
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter1.GetResult()    at
Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted[T](ValueTask`1
task)    at
Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetToken(TokenRequestContext
requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
HiSS.DB.DataAccessService.RunSP(String procedure, SqlParameter[]
paramlist, Object retObject) in
C:\Dev\HiSS\HiSS.DB\DataAccessService.cs:line 337
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]


Inner Exception 1: AggregateException: Multiple exceptions were
encountered while attempting to authenticate. (EnvironmentCredential
authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully
configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information.
https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot)
(WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload
options are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for
more information.
https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot)
(ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No response
received from the managed identity endpoint.) (Visual Studio Token
provider can't be accessed at
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json)
(Azure CLI not installed) (Az.Accounts module >= 2.2.0 is not
installed.) (Azure Developer CLI could not be found.)
Inner Exception 2: CredentialUnavailableException:
EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment
variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for
more information.
https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot

Update 2
Finally got it to connect by putting the environment variables at server level in IIS. If I put them at site level, they get overwritten every time I publish.
The only problem I'm getting now is that when connected to the DB, its not as my user, but a hex code. This messes up all my access rights as users are assigned certain roles in the DB. I've created a user as external provider as has been suggested via google, but I'm still getting just the hex value and not the login name.

I think we could firstly to make sure whether the issue is related to network or IIS configuration. If we could use tools like Azure Data Studio to connect to Azure Database from your IIS server, I'm afraid the network shall be good.

I can connect to the Azure DB with no problem from the IIS server using SSMS, so its not the network.

updated with a generated error now - so I need to set some environment variables by the look of it - not sure which ones though...

Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException HResult=0x80131500 Message=DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token ->if you want to set environment variable for DefaultAzureCredential() to get authenticated, you need to set AZURE_CLIENT_ID AZURE_TENANT_ID AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, see this section

I've done that now - I get a popup asking for me to login, when I enter the details, the same window pops up again. only way out is to cancel, and then the site is unauthorised.

Is the popup window the windows auth popup?

it is now, I had to enable anonymous login to allow the correct window to popup. progress has been made - see changes to the main post...
